# How can i protect app script code from the editor?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet, and I have shared it with 50 people for the editor role. I have written some js codes in app script but unfortunately, someone removed my code and the spreadsheet has been affected for the reason.

I need a solution so that no one views or accesses my app script code who has an editor role.

Comment: this does not send a message to Rubén ... please post a complete question about your problem ... someone will try to answer it ... include a description of what you tried, a description of what you do not understand and a description of any errors that you observed

Comment: I defer to @Rubén for a definitive answer/comment. In the meantime, I think I can clarify that the focus is not multiple spreadsheets (per se) but multiple projects. There aren't necessarily two spreadsheets but there **are** `two projects`. One project is bound to the "target spreadsheet"; this may or may nor contain code and any editor can view that code. But the second project (which need not be bound to a spreadsheet at all) references the "target spreadsheet" by ID. Editors of the target spreadsheet won't easily find the second project, so the code is effectively hidden from them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Your question needs to stand on its own. Even though you reference a related question, you need to write a question that explains the problem in as many words. @jsotola was right to ask for a complete question and your response of "you can follow the question title and that I need an answer." is inappropriate.

Comment: @Tedinoz question is updated!

Comment: _if someone re-write some codes using Extention > App Script from the spreadsheet menu, then they can override or make something new_ — a script project cannot "override" the functionality of another script project, although they may conflict or interfere. If you are on a Google Workspace domain, you can prevent editors from writing scripts using policies. If you use a gmail.com account, that cannot be done. Consider using a Google Form instead of sharing a spreadsheet.

Comment: Follow up questions should be posted as new questions, not as an edit of a question that already was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to protect a script from users who have editor access to the spreadsheet, depending on the nature of the script.

If the script runs when a time-driven trigger fires, it can be implemented as a [stand-alone script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that nobody else has access to.

If the script contains UI code such as dialog boxes or sidebars, you would have to rewrite the script as an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons).

The third option is to implement the script as a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) with only a few short stub functions in the script project that is bound to the spreadsheet, and the rest of the code in the library.

Comment: thanks for the peaceful suggestion. Which one do you recommend as the most secure way?

Comment: An add-on. There is a learning curve. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).